# Observe list of live data in java

Tags: java, android-livedata, android-architecture-components, mutablelivedata

I have a list of liveData, like `List<LiveData<String>>`. I want to observe this list so that whenever the `String` inside the `LiveData` changes, it would notify the observer of the list with this `String`.
How can I do this?
My list elements are strictly `LiveData<String>` so, it can not be simplified to `String`.
I know how to observe `LiveData<String>`, but not `List<LiveData<String>>`.
Please help.

> Edit:
>
> The element of the list is `LiveData<String>` because the `String` it is coming from the internet. So, list elements are holding object of `LiveData<String>`.

Comment: But, if every LiveData has its own observer, you already achieve what you aim...Regardless of where the LiveData is stored (in your example, a List), it will notify you the changes on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to observe a `List<LiveData<String>>`, you would have to attach an observer to each element of the list.  The list itself is not observable, only each LiveData element of it.  So, simply:

1. Iterate the List
2. Observe each LiveData element
3. Decide what you want to do for each observed element

Comment: How can I achieve step 2? How can I attach and keep track of each observer for each item of the list?

Comment: You can observe a LiveData as shown in the documentation.  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#work_livedata

Answer (score 0):

> I know how to observe LiveData, but not List<LiveData>.

It's not that hard, all you need to do is swap the `List<LiveData<String>>` to become a `LiveData<List<String>>`.

For that, you can use `MediatorLiveData`.

```
fun <T> List<LiveData<T>>.combineList(): LiveData<List<T>> = MediatorLiveData<List<T>>().also { mediator ->
    val mutableList = this.map { it.value }.toMutableList()

    mediator.value = ArrayList(mutableList).toList()

    forEachIndexed { index, liveData ->
        addSource(liveData) { value
            mutableList[index] = value
            mediator.value = ArrayList(mutableList).toList()
        }
    }
}
```

Which should be observable with a single observer

```
strings.combineList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { listOfStrings -> ... }
```

All code is directly convertable to Java, nothing Kotlin-specific is used in this answer.